# PDF reader with CGPDFDocumentRef

Tags: iphone, pdf, pdfrenderer

i'm going to make a PDF reader and i'm trying two possible solutions:

- UIWebView
- CGPDFDocumentRef

The first one is very simple, but is slower than the second one.
For the second one, i found a tutorial and i can view a pdf and i can zoom it with the two fingers movement. But at the moment i can't do 2 things :

1) View the PDF in landscape mode, maintaining the correct proportions.
2) Do a zoom in / zoom out with the double tap on the screen.

Those functions are already implemented in the UIWebView, but how said before, it's a little bit slow and it opens the entire PDF doc and not only a single page (so i need to split the file in many "one page pdf files").

Anyone can help me with some links/references/code about those kind of problems ?

Comment: Can u please provide the tute link ?

Comment: please provide the tutorial link

Answer (score 3):

With `CGPDFDocumentRef`, you need to get each page with `CGPDFDocumentGetPage` and then get the drawing transform with `CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform` and apply that to the `CGContextRef` before you draw the page.

Putting the view with your PDF page in a UIScrollView will let you zoom in and out, if you enable zooming. You can also draw it with a zoom factor using

```
    CGContextTranslateCTM (context, -sourceRect.origin.x * zoom, -sourceRect.origin.y * zoom);
    CGContextScaleCTM (context, zoom, zoom);
```

But you'll still run into the issue that very complex PDF pages will be slow to render, and every time you call `CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);` it has to render the entire page, such as when you change the zoom level. There are ways around this, such as drawing into a CATiledLayer.

Comment: Are you sure the entire page will be rendered on every draw? The renderer should be smart enough to not process all of the pdf data if rendering a clipped area, no?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, in the example that i found, he uses the CATiledLayer.
Here there is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CFURLRef pdfURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(
                                              CFBundleGetMainBundle(),
                                              CFSTR(filename),
                                              CFSTR("pdf"), NULL);
    myDocumentRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(pdfURL);
    myPageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(myDocumentRef, 1);
    CGRect pageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480); 

    tiledLayer = [CATiledLayer layer];
    tiledLayer.delegate = self;
    tiledLayer.tileSize = CGSizeMake(1024.0, 1024.0);
    tiledLayer.levelsOfDetail = 1000;
    tiledLayer.levelsOfDetailBias = 1000;
    tiledLayer.frame = pageRect;

    myContentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:pageRect];
    [myContentView.layer addSublayer:tiledLayer];

    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin = CGPointZero;
    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrame];
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.contentSize = pageRect.size;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 100;
    [scrollView addSubview:myContentView];

    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return myContentView;
}

- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(ctx));
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, layer.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(myPageRef, kCGPDFCropBox, layer.bounds, 0, true));
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, myPageRef);
}
```

This part works great, but if i want to introduce the landscape mode, i need to modify this part:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    if( (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||
       (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)){
        //SOMETHING TO DO FOR LANDSCAPE MODE
    }
    else if((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)){
        //SOMETHING TO DO TO RESTORE TO PORTRAIT
    }
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) ||
            (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||
            (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
}
```

I tried pratically everything, but i can't find a good solution !

Comment: How about this: save the orientation, then when you're drawing the PDF, if it's landscape, use CGContextRotateCTM to rotate the PDF.

Comment: Ok, but the problem is that if i call CGContextRotateCTM inside the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method, the transformation doesn't go ! I see that the only way to apply the transformation is to put it inside the drawLayer method. (And i don't know i can recall it manually)  Any suggestion or trick ?

Comment: Is there any way to display all the pages , same like uiwebview .?

Answer (score 0):

you can call draw layer method of any layer manually by saying
[yourLayer setNeedsDisplay]